# Two controllers, one model -- why is my app looking for a second model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have an Order model.

Customers get a handful of consumer-friendly views that let them create and view their own orders, all backed by an Orders controller.

Admins get the full range of views to create, edit, view, delete and manage orders, backed by a Purchases controller.

As far as I can tell, the Purchases controller should only be speaking to the Order model, but the following error message makes me think it's looking for a non-existant Purchase model:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PurchasesController#new
NameError in PurchasesController#new
uninitialized constant Purchase
Rails.root: /Users/steven/Dropbox/testivate
```

Is that what the error means? If it does, how do I stop the Purchases controller from trying to find a Purchase model?

My code...

**app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb:**

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @purchase = Order.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @purchase }
    end
  end
  def create
    @purchase = Order.new(params[:purchase])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @purchase.save
        format.html { redirect_to purchase_path(@purchase), notice: 'Purchase was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @purchase, status: :created, location: @purchase }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @purchase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**/config/routes.rb:**

```
Testivate::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :orders
  resources :purchases
end
```

**/app/views/purchases/new.html.haml:**

```
.textbox
  %p#notice= notice
  %h1 New Purchase
  = render 'form'
  = link_to 'List Purchases', purchases_path
```

**/app/views/purchases/_form.html.haml:**

```
= simple_form_for @purchase do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

***Update:** so I've just realised that 'transaction' is a reserved word in Rails so I've changed that. But is there anything else I need to fix?*

***Update 2:** When I completely comment out the #new view and the _form, I still get the error, so I think the problem is in my controller or routes or somewhere other than with my use of simple_form.*

Comment: Can you share all the fields you are using for Order model.

Comment: I tried your code in my local rails app, every thing seems working fine ( Under Rails 3.2)

Comment: t.string :company
      t.string :url
      t.string :comp1
      t.string :comp2
      t.string :comp3
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :guest_name
      t.string :guest_email
      t.string :market_list
      t.string :industry_list
      t.string :good_list
      t.timestamps

Comment: I can also confirm that it works fine in a test app.

Comment: Do you have any before/after filters in your application controller?

Comment: Is it the full code for the controller? Are you using CanCan, for example (and its `load_and_authorize_resource` filter)?

Comment: I've deleted my answer, since it was clearly wrong. I'll re-post if I find a better answer, but we need more info about the controller flow.

Comment: Shioyama, It turns out you had both parts of the answer. The first part was that I did have declarative_authorization calling a before filter on the controller -- a filter that was making an assumption about the model that would correspond to the controller. After I fixed that problem, I then encountered the simple_form problem you identified, fixing it with the code you posted earlier but then deleted. Thanks!

Comment: @steven_noble great! I've undeleted my answer below and posted a note explaining that it's half of the answer, and that the other half is in the comments here.

Comment: Fab. Happy to give it a tick. Now have a new problem! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682312/how-to-use-two-controllers-with-one-model-in-rails :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

This is half of the answer. For the other half see the comments on the question.

**Original answer:**

Part of the problem here is that by default `form_for` (which `simple_form_for` is built atop) assumes certain things about what paths to use for a given record, which it derives from the class of that record. In your case, since `@purchase` is actually an instance of the `Order` class, those assumptions are going to screw things up for you.

If you look at the form generated by `simple_form_for`, you'll see that it gives the form both an id and a class of `new_order`, and that the fields in the form have names like `order[name]`. To get rails to use `purchase` instead of `order` in the form, you have to pass it an `:as` option.

From the [docs for `form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style):

> If you have an object that needs to be represented as a different parameter, like a Person that acts as a Client:

And the example they give:

```
<%= form_for(@person, :as => :client) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In your case, you'd actually want to tell it to treat `@purchase` like a "purchase":

```
= simple_form_for @purchase, :as => :purchase do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

That will get the form ids, etc. right, so that you can use e.g. `params[:purchase]` in your create action as you have above. But this is not enough, because the action (URL) for the form will still end up being `/orders`. To change that, add an `:url` option:

```
= simple_form_for @purchase, :as => :purchase, :url => purchases_path(@purchase) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

This will also solve the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682312/how-to-use-two-controllers-with-one-model-in-rails#13682312) you posted.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually get the same error with a plain simple_form_for @order, so I'm not sure if this is it...?

Comment: Ah, actually I suspect the problem is here: `render 'form'`. You are passing `@purchase` implicitly, but this may involve assumptions about class names.

Comment: p.s. what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Hi Shioyama. I'm using Rails 3.2.8. I'm not sure I understand the other question. The form picks up @purchase from the purchase#new. This is how I do it all my views, except that the other views all work.

Comment: @steven_noble never mind, I'm not awake today. That's not the issue. In fact, I've re-created your situation in a simple app and I get no errors: even with one model, the `new` view renders fine. I haven't gone beyond that because you say you get that error simply from viewing the `new` purchase page. Is it possible there's something else involved here?