# How to use two controllers with one model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Order model. Customers interact with the Order model through an Orders controller. Admins interact with the Order model through a Purchases controller.

Mostly it's working, except this happens:

1. An admin user goes to new_purchase_path
2. The app uses the "create" action in the purchases controller, as
       expected
3. The app then uses the "new" action in the order controller (not the
   purchases controller)
4. App then renders the "app/purchases/new" view (not the
   "app/orders/new" view), despite the fact that it has switched to using the orders controller
5. After the admin creates the order, the app then renders the
   "app/orders/show" view using the orders controller

What I really need to happen is this:

1. An admin users goes to new_purchase_path
2. The app then uses the "create" action in the purchases controller
3. The app then uses the "new" action in the purchases controller
4. The app then renders the "app/purchases/new" view
5. After the admin creates the order, the app then renders the
   "app/purchases/show" view using the purchases controller

In app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb I have this:

```
  def new
    @purchase = Order.new
    respond_with @purchase
  end
```

If have tried variations like...

```
  def new
    @purchase = Order.new
    respond_with @purchase, :controller => :purchases
  end
```

...but nothing like that is documented for respond_with, and naturally it doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: I am not sure why you have `respond_with` try removing it. Also, I am not sure I understand the flow of events, specifically 2 & 3. What do you mean it uses purchases#create and then uses orders#new. If a user goes to new_purchase_path, purchases#new is the action that gets called.

Comment: @todd The question is confusing because it's based on a previous one, where there was some confusion (partially my fault): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676834/two-controllers-one-model-why-is-my-app-looking-for-a-second-model/13676976 I've updated my answer there, and added an answer here which I think explains what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is related to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676834/two-controllers-one-model-why-is-my-app-looking-for-a-second-model/13676976). I've updated [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676834/two-controllers-one-model-why-is-my-app-looking-for-a-second-model/13676976#13676976), but in a nutshell, the problem is not with `respond_with` (which as @jiri-pospisil points out you don't really need) but with your form generated by `simple_form_for`. The action url in that form defaults to `/orders` because `@purchase` is an instance of the class `Order`.

To fix that problem, specify the url in the form:

```
= simple_form_for @purchase, :as => :purchase, :url => purchases_path(@purchase) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

You'll then find that you have another problem: after the new order (purchase) is created, `respond_with` will redirect to the `show` action of `OrdersController`. To fix that, you can use the `location` option:

```
def create
  @purchase = Order.new(params[:purchase])
  if @purchase.save
    respond_with(@purchase, :location => purchases_path(@purchase))
    ...
```

As you can probably tell at this point, using two controllers for a single model this way becomes somewhat convoluted, so you might want to consider [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) instead.

Comment: Thanks. This does send me back to the purchases#show as requested at the end. Funnily enough though, when purchases#new is rendering the purchases/new view, it still shows a Create Order button, not a Create Purchase button. Odd.

Comment: Yes I was going to add a note about that. The reason is that `form_for` uses the `Order` class to find the appropriate text for the submit button. Normally you can customize that by adding a text in the right place in `config/locales.yml`, but it will look for the string in a place corresponding to (again) the class, so if you override it then it will also change the submit button on order forms. Basically, you're working against the grain.

Answer (score 3):

A few observations:

1. You should not use *respond_with* in the new action as it doesn't make sense for anything but HTML.
2. You should use namespaces if you want to make some controllers for admins only. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing. That way you also don't need to change the name.

Comment: +1 for suggesting namespaces as an alternative solution to this problem.

Comment: So, let me check I understand. Consumers interact with the Order model through an order controller in the global namespace. Admin users interact with a second order controller that is in the admin namespace. And when a user goes to admin/order#new, there will be no dramas -- the process flow will then progress naturally to admin/order#create and then admin/order#show without any nasty hacks to ensure this actually occurs. Right?